# Do I need to use thread for testing code execution speed in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, testing, benchmarking

I need to benchmark this code:

```
public static String foo () {

     final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
     try {
         // my code here
         final long endtime = System.nanoTime();
         System.out.println ("Total execution time:" + (endtime - startTime));
         return msg;
     } Catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
         return "ERROR";
     }
 }
```

Im gonna execute this code in 2 different android device with quadcore, do I need to use thread for benchmarking like this? if I execute it without thread will it affect the output?

edit: Im gonna need it to compare two algorithm pure speed for my college paper

Answer (score 0):

You can use DDMS and Systrace to know what your app is doing and for how long.

For bench marking, you should make sure you're doing things in the fastest or most optimized way possible, rather than within a certain time.

If you introduce Threads, your line of code will run parallel/asynchronously, it will divide your system resources to achieve its target, increasing number of threads introduces blocking (see [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)) in some causes its better to block some threads but sometimes you don't need to block your tasks.

So if you want to use Threads you will have to check blocking or rejection policy for your ThreadPool.

Its better to use threads instead of single task in certain period of time.